# $A_n$ Can be Generated by 3-Cycles with Consecutive Elements

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $ A_n $ be the alternating group on $n$ elements. I have already proven that $A_n$ can be generated by the set of 3-cycles with distinct elements. However, I am not sure how to further prove that $A_n$ can be generated by the set of 3-cycles with consecutive elements i.e. $ A_n = \langle (k,k+1,k+2) : 1 \leq k \leq n-2 \rangle$.

The natural thing to do is to show that an arbitrary 3-cycle with distinct elements can be generated by 3-cycles with consecutive elements, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction on $n$ plus transitivity of $A_n$, $n\ge3$, settle this.

**Base Case.**

The claim is clear when $n=3$.

**Inductive Step.**

I will use the natural identification of elements of $A_n$ with those elements of $A_{n+1}$ that map the number $n+1$ to itself.

Assume that $n\ge3$ and that the claim holds for $A_n$. We show that the claim holds for $A_{n+1}$ as well.

Let $\sigma\in A_{n+1}$ be arbitrary. Let $d=\sigma(n+1)$. If $d=n+1$, then $\sigma\in A_n$. And by the induction hypothesis, it is a product of 3-cycles of consecutive elements involving $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ only.

Otherwise $d<n+1$. Because $A_n$ is transitive, there is an element $\alpha\in A_n$ such that $\alpha(d)=n$. It follows that
$$
\beta:=(n-1;n;n+1)\alpha\sigma\in A_n
$$
because it maps the number $n+1$ to itseld.

Solving for $\sigma$ from this gives
$$
\sigma=\alpha^{-1}(n-1;n;n+1)^2\beta.
$$
The induction hypothesis says that as elements of $A_n$ both $\beta$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ can be written in terms of the prescribed generators. Hence so can $\sigma$. As $\sigma$ was an arbitrary element of $A_{n+1}$, the inductive step is valid.

---

An alternative, possibly closer to what the OP had in mind, could be the following:

1. Brute force it for $A_4$.
2. In the inductive step we can then assume that $n\ge4$. Thus we know that $A_n$ is doubly transitive.
3. In the inductive step it suffice to show that all 3-cycles of the form $(a;b;n+1)$ can be generated. But, by double transitivity there exists an element $\alpha\in A_n$ such that $\alpha(n-1)=a$ and $\alpha(n)=b$. The usual conjugation rule of cycles says that
   $$
   \alpha (n-1;n;n+1) \alpha^{-1}=(a;b;n+1).
   $$
   Here both $\alpha$ and its inverse can be written in terms of the prescribed generators, so $(a;b;n+1)$ is included, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for both solutions. I think I like the first one more because it doesn't involve manual calculations for $A_4$. The question I asked was a follow-on question from proving that $A_n$ is generated by 3-cycles, but since these proofs are nice and short it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Let p be a even permutation, expressing p as a product of consecutive 3-cycles is equivalent to saying can I multiple p with consecutive 3-cycles and get the identity permutation, this is true because of the following reasoning:

Let f1,f2,..fm be  3-cycles with consecutive elements such that,
p.f1.f2..fm = e, then p = inverse(f1f2...fm) = which is also a product of 3-cycles with consecutive elements.

The later problem of muliplying p with consecutive element 3-cycles to get an is easier to argue about. Here is the proof:

I will represent a permutation as an array, for example if f = [2, 3, 4, 1] represent the permutation f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 1

Given an array of size n, that represents a permutation p, then I claim the following

```
   We can sort the array using only rotations of 3-sized subarrays if and only if 
the permutation it represents is an even permutation
```

Multiplying a permutation by a consecutive 3-cycle is equivalent to selecting a subarray and rotating it once or twice.

let p be a even parity permutation of (1, 2, 3....n) represented as an array A,

Lets rotate 3-sized subarrays in A with the goal of moving 1 to position1, After accomplishing this goal we can focus on moving 2 to second position and so on. We will be able to do that for all the elements except the n-1 and n. So our final array after all these rotations could be one of the following:

option1: [1, 2 ,.....n-2, n-1, n] // fully sorted

Option2: [1, 2, .....n-2, n, n-1] // sorted except for the last two elements.

So to summarize, we took an even parity permutation p, multiplied it with 3-cycles and we claimed that we showed a way to reach either option1 or option2.

Since p is an even permutation, and each of 3-size subarray rotation is a 3-cycle multiplication and since 3-cycles are also even parity permutations, we must end up with a final permutation that is also even.  But amongst option1 and option2 only option1 is an even parity permutation. Hence if we start with an even parity permutation we must reach option1.

We demonstrated a way to multiply an even permutation with consecutive element 3-cycles and reaching identity element
(identity element is same as sorted array)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).